# User authenticating but not staying logged in Laravel 8.x

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8

When testing my application and trying to create a new user then on form submission I am getting error 419.

If I use a helper to log in using `Auth::loginUsingId(x)` for an existing user then `dd(auth()->user())` is successful but when I redirect to another page the user is no longer logged in. eg running the following code, you end up getting redirected to `/login`:

```
Route::get('/logInAs/{id}', function ($id) {
    Auth::loginUsingId((int) $id);
    dd(\auth()->user());
    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
});
```

I would share more code but I'm not sure what would be useful at this point?

I've probably spent about seven hours trying to fix this so far. It's driving me up the wall!

The app works fine on other environments, such as `staging`. I've even gone so far as to re-download it from github as a fresh install (in case I was messing about in `vendor` directory and changed something), but that hasn't fixed it.

I get the same issue on Chrome, using different signed in users on Chrome, using incognito mode on Chrome, using Firefox, and using `valet share` and accessing my local version on another device, like a phone, so I don't think it is to do with browser caching.

When other devs working on the project run it locally on their machines I haven't had reports of this issue, so it seems to just me my local environment.

I've variously tried changing `CACHE_DRIVER` and `SESSION_DRIVER` in `.env` to no joy, but I'm beginning to lose the will to live so don't really know if I'm doing the right thing there - please help if you can!!

### Edit to add more detail:

Middleware on the `dashboard` route:

```php
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard', DashboardController::class)->name('dashboard');
});
```

If I remove the middleware then I just get an error that `user` is `null` on `dashboard.blade.php`, ie the `user` is still not staying logged in.

A custom middleware:

```php
class VerifyUserIsMerchant
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user()->isMerchant()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('You must be a merchant to access this page');
    }
}
```

If I `dd($request->user())` in this middleware it returns `null`.

Comment: do you have multiple guard in your application ? maybe also try the command `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Does your routes have the middleware `auth:your-guard` ?

Comment: "The app works fine on other environments, such as staging" - other environments on the same machine?

Comment: @N69S Yes I have multiple guards. `config:clear` didn't work

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier no. I have edited my question to show the route for `dashboard` and a custom middleware. When I `dd($request->user())` in the `VerifyUserIsMerchant` middleware then I am getting `null`.

Comment: @levi not on the same machine, no. It works on forge and on other developers` machines.

Comment: _If I remove the middleware then I just get an error that user is null on dashboard.blade.php_ That's the point of the `auth` middleware. This is the middleware that authenticate you and therefore returns the authenticated user. Or am I getting your question wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ClémentBaconnier . The issue got solved on Laracasts - I've added the answer below.

Comment: The answer was to remove the `http://` protocol from `SESSION_DOMAIN` in `.env`. I put this as an answer but it was deleted by a moderator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got fixed with the help of Laracasts.

In short, I needed to remove the `http://` protocol from `SESSION_DOMAIN` in `.env` and set it to match `APP_URL`.